# Rename files automatically within IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, file, selenium-webdriver, automation, refactoring

Within my current Selenium Java test automation framework, I have a method that upload a file to the site I am testing, where I pass the absolute path to the method parameter. The absolute path of the file is the path where the different documents I have (docx, pptx, xlsx) are stored within my IDE folder structure. The challenge I have is that the website requires a unique filename, thus, prior to every test, I manually refactor the filenames and the absolute paths within the method parameter, get's updated with the new filename (I add a different digit at the end of the file name). Is there a manner in which I could potentially automate this process?

I've tried the method below with no success:

```
public void renameUploadFiles() {
    String folderPath = "C:/Project/src/main/resources/files";  // replace with the actual path to your folder

    File folder = new File(folderPath);
    File[] files = folder.listFiles();

    if (files == null) {
        System.err.println("Error: folder not found or not accessible");
        return;
    }

    Random random = new Random();

    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isHidden()) {  // skip hidden files (e.g. .DS_Store on macOS)
            continue;
        }
        String filename = file.getName();
        String extension = "";
        int dotIndex = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (dotIndex != -1) {
            extension = filename.substring(dotIndex);  // get the file extension if present
            filename = filename.substring(0, dotIndex);  // remove the extension for renaming
        }
        int randomDigit = random.nextInt(1000);  // generate a random digit from 0 to 1000
        File newFile = new File(folder, filename + "_" + randomDigit + extension);

        if (file.renameTo(newFile)) {
            System.out.println("Renamed file " + file.getName() + " to " + newFile.getName());
        } else {
            System.err.println("Error: could not rename file " + file.getName());
        }
    }

    System.out.println("File names refactored successfully!");
}
```

Comment: Who saves the files initially? 
Do the file names have any meaning?
You can consider saving the files with names which are UUID in the first place, that will guarantee unique names

Comment: Copy the files to a temporary location and rename the files as part of your test setup, and then use that temporary location in your test.

Comment: I found a solution, figured out the code. Thank you for your input and suggestions